# Converting numeric to date issues

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a date column that is numeric as follows

```
       Date1
       4010
       5178
       5494
       6750
       7106
       39
       39
       172
       1704
       4152
```

I am trying to convert this to real date using this function

```
 as.Date(df$Date1, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

However I am seeing that these numbers are converted to these dates which are incorrect.

```
    Date1_Converted
    1980-12-24
    1984-03-26
    1985-01-16
    1988-06-25
    1989-06-16
    1970-02-09
    1970-02-09
    1970-06-22
    1974-09-01
    1981-05-15
```

The correct transformation should have been

```
    Date1_CrctTrnsf
    2005.10.31
    2009.02.11
    2009.12.04        
    2013.05.15
    2014.05.06
    1994.02.22
    1994.02.22 
    1994.08.03
    1999.05.03
    2006.03.22
```

I am assuming this an origin issue, not sure how to fix this, any help on how to fix this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: You are correct on it being an origin issue. What does the data in Date1 column represent? It appears that R is treating those as days, so that is why you end up with the output in Date1_Converted(e.g. 4010/365 = 10.986 years which is approximately the difference in the dates of the origin and Date1_Converted. Would changing the origin help? Or do you need to use the origin already in place?

Comment: It looks like the difference in the number of days between the numeric values in `Date1` is not consistent with the number of days between the dates in `Date1_CrctTrnsf`. For example, looking at the second and third values, 5494 - 5178 = 316, while `as.numeric(as.Date("2009-12-04")) - as.numeric(as.Date("2009-02-11"))` = 296.

Comment: @small_data88, I tried changing the origin before, I changed the origin from `origin = "1970-01-01"` to `origin = "1994-01-15"` so that it  just converted 39 to `1994.02.22` but the remaining dates were incorrect.  You make a good point about those numbers representing days.

Comment: @BridgeportByronTucker It's actually `1994-11-08` and if you want the dots instead of dashes as in the example you can do that with `gsub`

Comment: @Hack-R, origin doesn't work, as you can see observation 6 should have been `1994.02.22` and not `1994.12.17` :)

Comment: Sorry got wrapped up in work, but it looks like your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# First I copied the data from your question
df <- read.table(con <-file("clipboard"), header = T)
df

# Convert the format
df1 <- as.Date(df$Date1, origin = "1994-11-08")
df1
> as.data.frame(gsub("-", ".", df1))
   gsub("-", ".", df1)
1           2005.10.31
2           2009.01.11
3           2009.11.23
4           2013.05.02
5           2014.04.23
6           1994.12.17
7           1994.12.17
8           1995.04.29
9           1999.07.09
10          2006.03.22
```

Note, however, that there seems to be an error in the data (or at least the results you are expecting to get from the data -- how did you produce these numbers?):

- The input for row 6 is **39**
- The input for row 7 is **39** and
- The input for row 8 is **172**

**172 - 39 = 133**

However you expect the dates for row 6 and 7 to be `1994.02.22` and the result for row 8 to be `1994.08.03`. *This is not mathematically possible, as there are 162 days between those 2 dates.*

[image: Day difference of 162 days]

Comment: I tried that before, the final output using origin does not produce accurate results, as you can see observation 6 should have been `1994.02.22`

Comment: See my comment above. The numeric values and the expected date output are not consistent. This is more than an origin issue. Is it certain that the numeric values are denominated in units of 1 day?

Comment: @eipi10 that is correct, I am trying the ymd function from lubridate. :)

Comment: @BridgeportByronTucker I think the mistake is in your data. Note that the input for result 6 and 7 is `39` and the input for row 8 is `172`. 172 - 39 = 133. However, there are 162 days in-between `1994.02.22` and `1994.08.03`. The `lubridate` package is great, but it won't be able to help you with incorrect data.

Comment: @Hack-R :) you are right something is messy, my data looks incorrect